# Space being treated as a delimiter in UNIX array

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, unix

I have a piece of code where I have a string delimited by / .

The last element of the code is a value "Cars & bikes"
But the code treats space as a delimiter and i get a wrong output.

```
ARG="s3://this-is-my-bucket/Load/Data/Cars & Bikes"
ARR=(${ARG//// })
S3=${ARR[0]}
AWS=${ARR[1]}
TYPE=${ARR[2]}
FIELD=${ARR[3]}
ITEM=${ARR[4]}
echo $S3
S3:
echo $AWS
this-is-my-bucket
echo $TYPE
Load 
echo $FIELD
Data
echo $ITEM
Cars
```

**What I want the o/p be like is**:

echo $ITEM

Cars & Bikes

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use code markup, not quotation

Comment: Quote your variables to prevent word splitting.

Comment: Refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92188 for a correct answer

Comment: @Theforgotten- Thats not a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read -a` with `/` as `IFS`:

```
s="s3://this-is-my-bucket/Load/Data/Cars & Bikes"
IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$s" && declare -p arr

declare -a arr=([0]="s3:" [1]="" [2]="this-is-my-bucket" [3]="Load" [4]="Data" [5]="Cars & Bikes")
```

Or else you can avoid array creation and directly use variables in `read` with `IFS=/` as this:

```
IFS=/ read -r s3 _ aws type field item <<< "$s" && declare -p s3 aws type field item
declare -- s3="s3:"
declare -- aws="this-is-my-bucket"
declare -- type="Load"
declare -- field="Data"
declare -- item="Cars & Bikes"
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Using IFS causes a regression issue. There are also more lines of code which follows right after the code that I/you mentioned. Incidentally, there we have "/" in unix path. So, having IFS set to / treats unix path also as delimiters. Can you please help me out to of how to stop/deativate IFS=/ after its use is done.

Comment: Having `IFS=/` in the same line as `read` doesn't set global `IFS` variable. In case you have set global `IFS` for some reason then use `unset IFS` to reset it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with shell script. It is bash, not sh.

Comment: Sorry don't understand

Answer (score -1):

Set `IFS` to change thw word delimiter from whitespace to `/`. And put variables in double quotes when you don't want word splitting.

```
ARG="s3://this-is-my-bucket/Load/Data/Cars & Bikes"
IFS=/
ARR=($ARG)
S3=${ARR[0]}
AWS=${ARR[2]}
TYPE=${ARR[3]}
FIELD=${ARR[4]}
ITEM=${ARR[5]}
echo "$S3"
echo "$AWS"
echo "$TYPE"
echo "$FIELD"
echo "$ITEM"
```

Note that since there are two `//` after `s3:`, you need to add 1 to the array indexes to get the following fields. Multiple sequences of `IFS` characters are only treated as a single delimiter when `IFS` contains the standard whitespace characters.

BTW, you should avoid using uppercase variable names. Those are intended for environment variables.

Comment: @Barmer - Note, there are 2 // after s3: . So, IFS=/ won't solve the isse.

Comment: @ParijatBose Good catch, I've adjusted the indexes for that.